# Calculator for calculating a long list of numbers while excluding text input

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a calculator which is going to be used for calculating a list of numbers while excluding text input (from the user). The lists will exclusively look like this (except for different values each time):

GOLD:    72,644 ELIXIR:   217,966 DARK:     2 TROPHIES: -19 SEARCHES:    4

GOLD:   188,643 ELIXIR:   226,899 DARK:   723 TROPHIES:   6 SEARCHES:    9

GOLD:   483,499 ELIXIR:   328,480 DARK: 1,214 TROPHIES:   3 SEARCHES:    1

GOLD:   182,237 ELIXIR:   385,613 DARK: 1,350 TROPHIES: -19 SEARCHES:    5

GOLD:   504,233 ELIXIR:   494,088 DARK:   357 TROPHIES: -24 SEARCHES:    2

I'm trying to find a way to grab specific values from this list while still keeping it in a single `<textarea>`. For example, I want calculate all of the "GOLD: x" inputs so I could get a list of those numbers.

The calculation is not the problem, I just need to know how to derive all the values from each "GOLD: x" input. From this list I would need to get the numbers 72.644, 188.643, 483.499, 182.237, 504.233, and the values for ELEXIR and DARK respectively. My questions is, how can I achieve that in javascript or html?

I haven't really got up to trying anything as I am a complete beginner in coding. I know I could define them as an array, but I don't know how to grab a set of information which includes certain tags such as "GOLD" and their respective numbers.

`<textarea id="logInput" rows="14" cols="95" placeholder="Paste log here"></textarea> //This is where the list will be entered`

Comment: So you want to transform this text/lines of text into lists of numbers, one list for gold/elixir/etc ?

Comment: "I haven't really got up to trying anything" That's not how this site works.  You try something, we help you out if you are stuck.  This is not a coding service.

Comment: @Jean-Alphonse I want to add all of the values in each column, for example GOLD, into a list which could then be used for adding the new values together (so the sum of the list).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the value, then replace all new line with `' '` & then create an array by delimiter `' '`.

Iterate over this array and and check for specific word like `gold:` because you need the value after this text.

```js
function getValue() {
  let arr = [];
  let val = document.getElementById('logInput').value
    .replace(/\n/g, ' ')
    .split(' ');
  for (let i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
    if (val[i].trim().toLowerCase() === 'gold:') {
      arr.push(val[i + 1]);
    }
  }

  console.log(arr)
}
```

```html
<textarea id="logInput" rows="14" cols="95" placeholder="Paste log here">
GOLD: 72,644 ELIXIR: 217,966 DARK: 2 TROPHIES: -19 SEARCHES: 4 
GOLD: 188,643 ELIXIR: 226,899 DARK: 723 TROPHIES: 6 SEARCHES: 9 
GOLD: 483,499 ELIXIR: 328,480 DARK: 1,214 TROPHIES: 3 SEARCHES: 1 
GOLD: 182,237 ELIXIR: 385,613 DARK: 1,350 TROPHIES: -19 SEARCHES: 5 
GOLD: 504,233 ELIXIR: 494,088 DARK: 357 TROPHIES: -24 SEARCHES: 2</textarea>
<button type='button' onclick='getValue()'>Get Value</button>
```

Comment: This works like a charm for all the fields, thanks a lot!. However, I would like to use the values that I now have derived from the input. I updated and it currently looks like this in the console: [ "72,644", "188,643", "483,499", "182,237", "504,233" ]. Is there anyway I can make use of those numbers now, such as in adding them together? I don't think it's possible since their output is in the console, right? Sorry to bother you more, and maybe this should be a new question instead?

Answer (score 0):

You could get the parts of a single line by matching the label and value.

```js
function getParts(string) {
    var parts = string.match(/\S+(?=:)|[0-9,]+/g),
        result = {},
        i = 0;
        
    while (i < parts.length) {
        result[parts[i++]] = parts[i++];
    }
    return result;
}

var string = 'GOLD: 72,644 ELIXIR: 217,966 DARK: 2 TROPHIES: -19 SEARCHES: 4 ';

console.log(getParts(string));
```

For using it with a `<textarea>`, you could add a butten for getting the values.

```js
function getValues() {
    var data = document.getElementById('logInput').value,
        parts = data.split(/\n/),
        values = parts.map(getParts);
    
    console.log(values);
}

function getParts(string) {
    var parts = string.match(/\S+(?=:)|[0-9,]+/g),
        result = {},
        i = 0;

    if (!parts) return {};

    while (i < parts.length) result[parts[i++]] = parts[i++];

    return result;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="logInput" rows="5" cols="75" placeholder="Paste log here">GOLD: 72,644 ELIXIR: 217,966 DARK: 2 TROPHIES: -19 SEARCHES: 4 
GOLD: 188,643 ELIXIR: 226,899 DARK: 723 TROPHIES: 6 SEARCHES: 9 
GOLD: 483,499 ELIXIR: 328,480 DARK: 1,214 TROPHIES: 3 SEARCHES: 1 
GOLD: 182,237 ELIXIR: 385,613 DARK: 1,350 TROPHIES: -19 SEARCHES: 5 
GOLD: 504,233 ELIXIR: 494,088 DARK: 357 TROPHIES: -24 SEARCHES: 2</textarea><br>
<button onclick="getValues()">parse</button>
```